# Android ListView keeps getting cut off

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

For some reason when the `listview` in my fragment is loaded it gets cut off at the first row however the same code is used in other `listfragments` in my app and those are fine ???...
Here is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#eeeeee">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="#eeeeee"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is the fragment class .. I dont the fault lies with the adapter class as I am using that in the other fragments that are working.

```
    public class TabTwoFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String TAG = AccommodationFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.mywebsite.com/json.php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private View mheaderView;
    //private TextView txtFragmentone;
    public static TabTwoFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        TabTwoFragment fragment = new TabTwoFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.accommodation_fragment, container, false);
        rootView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));

        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);



        mheaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.seturl(obj.getString("url"));
                                /*movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                        .doubleValue());*/
                                movie.setYear(obj.getString("releaseYear"));

                                // Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });






        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);




        return rootView;


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
        setListAdapter(null);
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    /*  if (mheaderView != null) listView.addHeaderView(mheaderView);*/
    // Don't forget to now call setListAdapter()
            this.setListAdapter(adapter);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Movie m= movieList.get(position);
        String yourURL = m.geturl();
        MyDetailFragment myDetailFragment = new MyDetailFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("YourKey", yourURL);
        myDetailFragment.setArguments(args);



    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, myDetailFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
```

I have no idea why it is cutting off my listview and I really can't find a solution on my own.... so any help would be great!

Comment: What's the size of the parent of your `LinearLayout` ? Most likely that is very small, and therefore your linearlayout + listview are limited in height.

Comment: It should be something to do with your container used for fragment, please post the layout of your Activity